# How to recover deleted changelist in Perforce

Tags: perforce, changelist

I use P4V. Once I changed logged user I saw only empty folder in one of workspaces and I couldn't load any content. So I marked this empty folder to delete - it made relevant changelist but didn't remove this folder from workspace. After some other tries I finally managed to connect with correct workspace. As the changelist has not been needed anymore I deleted it. Then I expanded the workspace content and what I saw was all files marked for delete. We tried to unmark them but we didn't manage to do so. So we marked all them once again to delete to create a changelist as we wanted then revert this hoping it will remove to-be-deleted marks. Suddenly P4V started removing all files from the project! Then I stopped the application and once run again I reverted this changelist. Ok, files have been restored BUT on all of them to-be-deleted mark from previous operation is still visible - even for other users in other locations. Does anyone know how to remove this mark?

Comment: Have you tried doing a `Get Latest Revision` on the files in question?

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work. All other machines 'see' these files as marked for deletion - even new workspace. Ordinary Refresh should unmark this but it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

Select the file, go to the "Files" pane on the right-hand side, and click the "Checked Out By" tab.  This will show you what user and workspace has the file opened for delete, and in what changelist.  You can go to that workspace and "revert" the file, or you can delete the workspace -- either way that workspace will no longer have the file open and the blue mark will go away.

Comment: Sam thank you very much for your response. I didn't have a chance to apply it since some other team member from another location resolved that. Anyway thank you once again. I hope it will be useful for someone else in the future.